(PyCharm) Discord bot (written in python) if "Hello" in message.content.lowe(): Not responding
import discord, os

TOKEN = 'I CANT POST IT IN THE FORM'

intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True
intents.messages = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('$hello'):

            await message.channel.send('Hello!')

            if "Hello" in message.content.lower():

                await message.channel.send('i found hello in the message,SUCSESS!')

client.run(TOKEN)


When typing $hello in the server
discord  bot returns:Hello!
When typing hello/Hello
discord bot does not respond.
code copied from replit toturial so some things may be  different and not work.

"Hello" will never be in .lower().

Well I changed it and the bot still doesn't answer,Now when typing $hello the bot answers: Hello! i found hello in the message,SUCSESS! and when typing: hello/Hello nothing happens

It's because you have an if statement to first check if the message starts with "$hello", meaning if you only send "hello" then the if statement returns false and the rest of the code is skipped. Likely you need to look at how you indent the code

You are literally checking if "Hello" is equal to "hello", which is of course false!
You should be doing this instead:
EDITED: Also fix your indentation! Both if statements should be at the same indentation. Currently you have indented the if statement (which is not working) inside that .startswith statement.
if "hello" in message.content.lower():
    await message.channel.send('i found hello in the message,SUCSESS!')

OR if you really (I mean "really") want to keep the "Hello" in your if statement, make it lower as well:
if "Hello".lower() in message.content.lower():
    await message.channel.send('i found hello in the message,SUCSESS!')

EDIT_2:

Fix Indentation
Fix logic
Use elif ! (why always asking 3 questions when only one going to be True at a time?)

@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.author == client.user:
        return

    elif msg.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await msg.channel.send('Hello!')

    elif "hello" in msg.content.lower():
        await msg.channel.send('i found hello in the message,SUCSESS!')


You also have to mention that OPs indentation is wrong

Well I changed   it and the bot still doesn't answer,Now when typing $hello the bot answers: Hello!
i found hello in the message,SUCSESS!
and when typing: hello/Hello nothing happens

@ŁukaszKwieciński yea, overlook that. the indentation is indeed wrong. That line of code is never going to execute as:
if message.content.startswith('$hello') is True, then after running this line, your function will return: await message.channel.send('Hello!') and never reach that other if statement (nested inside it) and if the condition message.content.startswith('$hello')  is False, it not even going to enter that if statement. Makes sense, right?

Also, instead of using three if statements, you should change other two if statements to elif.

Thank you so much! I didn’t change the code yet but it makes 100% sense,I wanted to use elif but because I didn’t have some settings turned on in the discord developer portal the whole code didn’t work so I just trashed the whole elif idea
